# PHP Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcached). Very infrequent

Tags: php, session, memcached

I installed memcached (2.2.0) libmemached (1.0.18) a few weeks ago. (Apache/2.4.10 and PHP 5.5.20), mostly for php session management.  Generally I'm really pleased with performance but I notice this warning occasionally. It happens 2 or 3 times a day and I get 3 of the messages at a time (within seconds).  I'm probably running about 50,000 sessions a day - so it's only a tiny fraction.

I can't reproduce.  And i see nothing googling it that helps. All the memcached config settings are standard and I started the daemon from command line: `memcached -d -u nobody -m 128 127.0.0.1 -p 11211`

Could something funny at the client end be causing these rare hiccups?

Update... found clue...

```
; The amount of retries for failed store commands.
; This mechanism allows transparent fail-over to secondary servers when
; set/increment/decrement/setMulti operations fail on the desired server in a multi-server
; environment.
; the default is 2
memcached.store_retry_count = 2
```

This probably explains why my warnings come in threes.  I'm guessing its a locking issue?  But I don't know why a session would lock (I mean the session is only used by the single user and he can only be performing a single script at the same time?)